# How to update DE containing millions of records without primary key field

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-template, ssjs, automationstudio, wsproxy

I tried updating large batch of records(millions of records), but i couldn't.What would be the mistake in this code?

```javascript
    var props = [ 
        {  
            "Name": "JOBID",  
            "Value": "****"   
        },   
        {    
            "Name": "BATCHID", 
            "Value": "****"    
        } 
    ]; 
    
    var options = {     
        SaveOptions: [    
            {        
                PropertyName: 'EmailAddress', 
                SaveAction: 'UpdateAdd'   
            } 
        ] 
    };   
    
    var result = api.updateItem('DataExtensionObject', { 
        CustomerKey: customerKey,  
        Properties: props 
    }, options);
```

Comment: SQL would be more efficient for this. Have you considered creating a copy of this DE and using queries to copy and overwrite the values in the original DE?

Comment: Let me try that, But it has millions of records, Will that cause timeout issue

Comment: I would advise to do that on test copies of DE's to see how it performs before doing the final overwrite.

Comment: its impossible to update because the DE Doesn't have primary key field

Comment: I suggest you will create a similar DE, with a primary key. Possibly as a so called compound key, on multiple fields. Assuming your keys are unique, you will populate this data extension with a SELECT * from your source DE. This will allow you to update the records, as you will now have a primary key. Once done, you can update your records and do an overwrite of your original DE with the updated data

Comment: I need to update the existing DE only @LukasLunow

Comment: How would you do this without the primary key? It is simply not possible. Utilising an extra DE is the only way forward

Comment: it can be done using ssjs

Comment: As @sfmc said, there is a core function in SSJS that can do this - but it is process heavy and honestly without a key, this can be cumbersome to get to work. Honestly, although possible, the lower risk, more efficient solution would likely be to utilize a second DE as stated above.

Comment: Thanks for the added insight on the SSJS approach, @Gortonington